# Escape special characters for Oracle and SQL Server in the same query

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-like

I have following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE REDUCTION LIKE '50%'
```

I'm required to use the LIKE clause. This query needs to run on both Oracle and SQL Server.

Now there is an issue because I want to match all products with a reduction of 50%. But the data might contain a reduction of 50.50%. Because '%' is a special character it matches both of them.

I want to escape all special characters, like the **`%`** in my query so that I only get the products with 50% reduction.

Is there an uniform solution to escape special characters on a dynamical way for both Oracle and SQL server?

Using a backslash is not a solution, because we don't know in practice what the input will be.

Comment: The `REDUCTION` is a `VARCHAR2` column and you want all rows with `50%`, right? So simple use `REDUCTION = '50%'`, works on any RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ESCAPE` clause works in [Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=edee71fdf33f047e14713eb4d93d853e) and [SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=edee71fdf33f047e14713eb4d93d853e).

As for your input, you need to replace the all occurrences of `%` with `\%` (preferably before passing the value to RDBMs). You can do this inside a query as well since, fortunately, Oracle `REPLACE` and SQL Server `REPLACE` functions have similar signature:

```
CREATE TABLE tests(test VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO tests VALUES('%WINDIR%\SYSTEM32');
SELECT *
FROM tests
WHERE test LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE('%WINDIR%\SYSTEM32', '\', '\\'), '%', '\%') ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works on both database types. So it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The ESCAPE clause identifies the backslash (\) as the escape character

```
SELECT *
FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE REDUCTION LIKE '50\%'
```

Comment: And what with dynamic queries? In practise this comes from an input value

Comment: You forgot to add the escape clause... without it, the \ is just another regular char...

Comment: you need to add `escape '\'` to that condition to make it work reliably.

Comment: you can concatenate with the input value LIKE :value||'\%'

Comment: @Sulejmani you're supposed to escape the input... replace all `%` with `\%`s.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something like the first answer above, but you don't need to use a `\` as the escape. You can choose whatever you want using the `ESCAPE` clause.

But if:

- users are allowed to enter wildcards;
- and you need to use LIKE;
- and you don't want them treated like wildcards;

then you have to escape them somehow.

Perhaps you can reserve some char you know the user will not need and make that the escape char.

As far as I can tell in [Oracle you only need to escape the percent (%) and the underbar (_)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm).
In [SQL Server you also have to consider brackets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-wildcard-characters-as-literals).

A good thing is that overescaping does not look like it will cause problems, so even though you don't need to espace brackets in Oracle, doing so is ok.